# Grub на загрузочной флешке

Tags: grub

Здравствуйте! Нужно установить Grub2 на флешку, на другой флешке cделал LiveCD Debian, там нет grub, grub-install. Как можно еще установить Grub?

Answer (score 0):

Из-за ограничений по времени, пришлось установить другой LiveCD с Ubuntu, там Grub на месте, все получилось, спасибо